Windows 11 Submenu Misaligned
I'm encountering a persistent UI glitch in the Windows 11 context menu, specifically with the "New" submenu. When I hover over the "New" option, the submenu displays with an extra empty row at the bottom (when menu open upward), which often leads to the submenu closing unexpectedly when trying to select an option. When submenu open downward it is well align and this problem do not occur.
I'm adding a screenshot to visualize it.
Here's what I've tried so far without success:

Adjusting display scaling and layout settings.
Running the System File Checker tool (sfc /scannow).
Updating graphics drivers.
Tweaking visual effects settings for best performance/appearance.
Ensuring Windows is up to date with all available updates.
Check on other users on this computer - behaviour is same.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can suggest other troubleshooting steps I might try? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated.

And this is how it is correctly displayed downward:


Your screenshot does not differ from the submenu for the context menu on my 23H2 system.

Interesting: in Win 10, the bottom line of submenu (WinRAR, in this case) is on the same level as the menu item New. Wonder why MS made that change?

Mine is like Ramhound's and OPs.

My semi-serious recommendation: Just disable the new context menus entirely, they suck anyway.

I added screenshot showing how it is correctly displayed when open downward

They look identical other than the orientation neither look incorrect

This is of course not correct, there is no need to discuss this. It is well-established how submenus should behave and has been for decades. // Since this is a bug in Windows, Feedback Hub is the way to go. It unfortunately is also where feedback goes to die.
